# css how do I realize cut-out borders?

Tags: html, css, border

I have this page mockup.

[image]

How do I realize that cut-Out border on the left?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this question:

1. Just use a triangle graphic.
   Easy, obvious answer. Probably not what you were looking for, though.
2. Use a filled in square div, and rotate it 45 degrees.
   It works, but is probably overkill for something so simple. Plus rotation can be a bit painful in older versions of IE (it works, but the `filter` syntax is horrible, and the default rotation point is different from all other browsers, so it can be hairy to get it right). Probably too much effort for a simple effect like this.
3. Use the CSS triangular-borders hack to make triangles.
   It's a bit hacky, but it works well. Read more about it here: http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/
4. Use SVG.
   SVG is an XML-based vector graphics format. It is trivial to create something like this in SVG. This would be a great solution, except that IE8 and earlier don't support SVG. Fortunately though, the do support VML, a competing format (IE9 supports SVG, so VML is going to die, but we need to deal with it for the time being). A good solution to this is to use one of the javascript libraries that do SVG-VML conversion on the fly. There's several of them - try this one for example: http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/. Or you can use the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library to draw in either SVG or VML using javascript.

Which one of these solutions you use is up to you; it depends on what browsers you want to support, whether you're happy with using Javascript, whether you want to avoid adding unnecessary graphics, etc.

I would suggest that the CSS triangular borders hack is probably the best solution for the time being. In the future, SVG will be a better answer, but for now the fact that IE8/7/6 don't support it is a bit of a killer.

The only problem with the triangular borders hack is that it doesn't work in 100% IE6 (see the page linked above for details on that), but even then it's usable. And frankly, I'd just drop support for IE6 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/WP7gY/

This is the simplest technique I can think of: put a `background` on the `h2`, and position it `left center`.

```
h2 {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(black-triangle-image.png) left center no-repeat
}
```

You'll have to replace any `margin-left` with `padding-left` on the `h2`.

If the container has some `padding-left`, you can set `margin-left: -??px` on the `h2` to pull it to the left edge.